# Django: Jquery formset js does not change id properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

The JS works fine with adding rows in a table for inlineformset. However Id is not coming properly.
Have included formset.js in media folder.
Using Django 1.8 with Python 3.4. [Django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst)

Output should be id_expenseitems1-2-Product and getting id_expenseitems1-NaN-Product.
Any solution!!!

Code in Html Template:

```
<form action="." method="post">
<table class="table"><tr>
{{ receipt_form.as_table }}</tr></table>
{{ new_formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
<table id="myForm" class="table">
{{ new_formset.management_form }}
{% for form in new_formset.forms %}
{% if forloop.first %}
<thead><tr>
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr></thead>
{% endif %}
<tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<td>
{# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
{% if forloop.first %}
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{{ field.errors.as_ul }}
{{ field }}
</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#myForm tbody tr').formset({

        });
    })
</script>
```